# Adding a service and removing it under next condition

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I need to start a service and end it under some condition. I previously used **IntentService** which I found to be incorrect for the purpose(if I am right). I have started using **service** with **BroadcastReciever**. But still can't get the desired result. I may elaborate or even paste my code if needed. But for now, I just need something like a flow chart or pseudocode.
The condition would be checked from **Preference** settings. If checked, I would like to run the service in background else stop the service. Please, can any one out here help me.

**EDITED:**

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LocalWorldService s;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalWorldService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            LocalWorldService.MyBinder b = (LocalWorldService.MyBinder) binder;
            s = b.getService();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            s = null;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
    };
```

My Service:

```
public class LocalWorldService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Magnet is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder{
        LocalWorldService getService(){
            return LocalWorldService.this;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getWordList(){
        return list;
    }
```

Following are two class for BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 15 * 1000;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
    }
```

And:

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent service = new Intent(context, LocalWorldService.class);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Map<String, ?> x = pref.getAll();
        boolean momoMagnetIsOn = (Boolean) x.get("key_momo_magnet");
        if (momoMagnetIsOn){
            context.startService(service);
        }
        else{
            context.stopService(service);
        }
    }
```

**CORRECTION:**
I need to override onDestroy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `onDestroy` method in Service
When ever you want to start a service all you need is

```
 startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

And to Stop a service anytime just call

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

Remember service needs to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml. As you said that your service is working. I'm sure you have done that. Still AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MainService" />
```

Comment: this will start different service each time and won't stop desired service

Comment: only one instance running not different

Comment: Check the condition only

Comment: u write on destroy in that ?

Comment: override onDestroy method in Service

Comment: what will that do? will it stop the service according to my boolean?

Comment: But the Toast that I kept inside onstartcommand won't go. If I use system.out.ln("somehting") then it would display very frequently on logcat unlike the time as mentioned. What is that?